# Mapbox gl long/lat goes outside the boundaries

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to display a simple marker on a map using the aws amplify react ui library. I'm able to get a map to display no problem but only when using coordinates that don't go outside the bounds [90, -90]. If I try to render a map with coordinates outside that zone I get:

```
Error: Invalid LngLat latitude value: must be between -90 and 90
at new Ou (maplibre-gl.js?48ec:31:280338)
at Ou.convert (maplibre-gl.js?48ec:31:280974)
at Map.jumpTo (maplibre-gl.js?48ec:35:288561)
at new Map (maplibre-gl.js?48ec:35:318676)
at Mapbox._initialize (mapbox.js?699b:219:1)
at new Mapbox (mapbox.js?699b:131:1)
at eval (map.js?48e9:61:1)
```

I've taken a look at the [react-map-gl api reference](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/map#initialviewstate) and I've seen that you could specify the initial bounds of the map. When trying to pass it something outside the [90, -90] range I still get the same error. I also tried to look up that error but I'm unable to get any results related to it. Here is what my component looks like:

```
import { MapView } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import 'maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css';
import 'maplibre-gl-js-amplify/dist/public/amplify-map.css';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import { Marker, LngLatBounds } from 'react-map-gl';

<MapView
      initialViewState={{
        longitude: location.longitude,
        latitude: location.latitude,
        zoom: 16,
        bounds: [-200, 200],
      }}
      style={{ width: '600px', height: '600px' }}
    >
      <Marker latitude={location.latitude} longitude={location.longitude} />
    </MapView>
```

For reference, the long/lat I'm trying to render is `{longitude: -79.3783434, latitude: 243.6539116}`. I haven't worked much with mapbox but I feel I'm missing something obvious as it doesn't really make sense that the bounds are so small. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concept of bonds is a bit off.
According to the [docs on bounds](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/map#initialviewstate) and on [lnglat](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/types#lnglatboundslike):

> bounds?: LngLatBoundsLike - The initial bounds of the map. If specified, it overrides the longitude, latitude and zoom options. Default null.

> A LngLatBounds object, an array of LngLatLike objects in [sw, ne] order, or an array of numbers in [west, south, east, north] order.

The bounds setting is a rectangle, and you need to provide the corners. The southwest (sw) and the northeast (ne) corners.

This means:

1. Bounds are optional. You can leave them out since you're providing a latitude, a longitude and a zoom level.
2. If you want to provide bounds anyways, they should be in one of these formats (notice there are 4 numbers, not just 2):

   1. `[[sw_longitude, sw_latitude], [ne_longitude, ne_latitude]]`, or
   2. `[sw_longitude, sw_latitude, ne_longitude, ne_latitude]`

And their min/max values are:

1. sw_longitude = -180/180
2. sw_latitude = -90/90
3. ne_longitude = -180/180
4. ne_latitude = -90/90

Additionally, these are called normalized longitude and latitude.
To normalize your longitude and latitude values, you need to wrap them around the globe. Here's a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/missinglink/d0a085188a8eab2ca66db385bb7c023a) that does that.

Notice that for longitude you just need to add +- 360 to the value until the value falls in the -180 180 range. For latitude though, you need to wrap it around the pole and flip the longitude, because when you cross the pole you start subtracting the latitude values one by one, and you end in the opposite of your old longitude.
The image [here](https://journeynorth.org/tm/LongitudeIntro.html) may make it more clear to visualize it:
[image: Latitude and longitude in a globe]

Comment: Really detailed answer, thank you. I'll try it in a bit and then accept the answer